# Which dlls blazor client project should have? Security issue?

Tags: c#, security, dll, blazor-webassembly

I'm studying Blazor (WebAssembly+Asp.net Core) and I have some doubts.

The client project compiles all c# code to run in browser, right?

It's include the dll dependencies, right?

So, if I have a domain dll included in client project, my business rules will be exposed if reverse engineering is used, right?

So, which dlls have to be included as dependency in a client project?

Comment: Yes. If your client code depends on an assembly containing business logic, it will get deployed to the client.  You should consider taking out your service interfaces into its own assembly, and use them to invoke the business logic running on the server.

Answer (score -2):

Working for NASA, are you?

If there are proprietary things you're worried about, like a new compression algorithm that you don't want anybody else to know about, then don't send packaged code to the consumer-- use a web API.

But really, though, what are you doing that's so valuable that someone will take the time to reverse-engineer all your code?